# Skip periods in a Scheduled Service

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

In my webapp, I am currently running a daily service basically like this:

```
private ScheduledExecutorService ses 
    = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
// ...
long repeat = 86400; // for daily 
long start = 4324; // e.g., some automatic calculated value..
ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new myTask(), start, repeat, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Due to some system maintenace, now I have to skip the task on the weekend.

One possible solution would be to run a weekly scheduler for each single day (one weekly scheduler for mondays, one for tuesdays etc..) but I'd like to acoid that. As well as I'd like to avoid to use some third party libraries.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, have you considered using quartz?

Comment: Thanks for this hint, but as mentioned I'd like to avoid 3rd party libs, if possible

Comment: A couple options I can think of (neither of which I am a fan of) - use fixed rate scheduling and make the task aware of the execution timing to decide to run or not, or your task decides the next runtime and calls `schedule`